# Connection with 000webhost sql from android apps

Tags: android, mysql

This is my domain name in 000webhost

http://sofebos.site88.net

I have put create_booking.php file in public_html in the website.

Thus, if I want to call the url to create booking, is this the url?

private static String url_create_product = "http://sofebos.site88.net/public_html/create_booking.php";

Comment: we have no idea how your server is configured, but most likely "public_html" would NOT be in any of your site's urls.

Comment: @MarcB This is the free hosting server, I have moved all the php file to a new directory named "webservices", however the error show in eclipse is that java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "sofebos.site88.net": No address associated with hostname

Comment: You only have the `default.php` in `public_htm`. The correct url  would be `http://sofebos.site88.net/create_booking.php`